# Extract daily range from time series using Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

*New to the huge Pandas library.*

I have an hourly data frame e.g.:

```
            date_time     open     high      low     close      volume
97759 2014-07-17 18:00:00  0.93702  0.93790  0.93696  0.93789    2098
```

I need to do processing on a daily basis but with the hourly data for that relative day.

1) How do I loop over it daily, and

2) how do I then extract the hourly time series for that day alone (in order to loop over it again perhaps or get max/min values, etc)?

Comment: Are you talking about [resampling](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#up-and-downsampling)

Comment: @EdChum I don't know but it doesn't look like it. I still need the hourly data, just every day's hourly data on it's own. I thought for the daily loop that I can somehow use `groupBy` or `bday()` and maybe get a new frame from it?

Comment: you should short a sample input (more than 1 line) and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea with groupby.  It has the ability to split up your data by the day then give you access to those groups.  The trick here is using the apply method on the Series df['date_time'].  Apply on a series applies the input method element wise and returns a new Series.  You can use this to split up by days and then again to split up by hours.

**input**

```
df = """            date_time     open     high      low     close      volume
97759  2014-07-17 18:00:00  0.93702  0.93790  0.93696  0.93789    2098
97758  2014-07-18 19:00:00  0.93702  0.93790  0.93696  0.93789    2098
97756  2014-07-18 20:00:00  0.93702  0.93790  0.93696  0.93789    2098"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df),sep="\s\s+")
df['date_time'] = df["date_time"].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
```

**solution**

```
#groupSeries = df["date_time"].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).date() ) #if date_time column isn't already datetime
groupSeries = df["date_time"].apply(lambda x: x.date() ) #if date_time column is datetime obj

grouped =  df.groupby(groupSeries)
for k,g in grouped:
    print k,"\n",g,"\n"*2
```

**output**

```
key: 2014-07-17 
                date_time     open    high      low    close  volume
97759 2014-07-17 18:00:00  0.93702  0.9379  0.93696  0.93789    2098 

key: 2014-07-18 
                date_time     open    high      low    close  volume
97758 2014-07-18 19:00:00  0.93702  0.9379  0.93696  0.93789    2098
97756 2014-07-18 20:00:00  0.93702  0.9379  0.93696  0.93789    2098
```